# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{ n!}$ equals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{ n!} $ equals

I'm not able to convert in any standard series? Any hints?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks for sharing that. But before you flag it -- How am I supposed to know if the question is asked? When I ask my question there it didnt show any similar of such this type? So unless the search of math.stackexchange is improved no way this can be stopped.

Comment: @NS: asking duplicate questions is not a crime, especially since the search function on Math.SE leaves much to be desired. On the other hand, it helps a lot for the site's overall organization to point out such duplicates when one is aware of them (which is what kingW3 did).

Comment: @WillieWong  I apologise if was being rude. But speaking from past experiences when I was very new to this amazing platform a few users were very hostile to me. So I apologise. Its really great to learn here.

Comment: @NS As Willie said it's not something that is bad,once I voted the question I asked as a duplicate,anyway I up-voted your question since it's a nice question.

Comment: But thanks for marking it as duplicate. It'll be deleted within a month. *slow claps* I dont think this question is at all redundant. The discussions done here is totally new and enlightening. But hey who cares!! This has to be deleted as ITS a DUPLICATE!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write, for $n =2,3,4,...$:
$$
\frac{n^2}{ n!}=\frac{n^2-n+n}{ n!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{ n!}+\frac{n}{ n!}=\frac{1}{ (n-2)!}+\frac{1}{ (n-1)!}
$$ and use a change of indices in the new infinite sums.

Comment: Yes Each of the sum is e. So 2e. I wish you just gave the hint only :(

Answer (score 2):

HINT: First do the obvious cancellation:

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n^2}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}\;.$$

Now consider performing some familiar operations on the well-known power series expansion of $e^x$.

**Added:** Multiply

$$e^x=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

by $x$ and differentiate:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^x\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(n+1)x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\;.$$

Comment: And which familiar power series expansion is that? I'm looking but not getting any of this type.

Comment: @NS: Do you know a power series for $e^x$?

Comment: By writing the numerator as n-1+1 it'll ultimately get converted into the above answer by Olivier form. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @NS: No. What happens if you multiply the power series that you know by $x$?

Comment: Yes I know. $ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^k}{k!} $

Comment: No that I dont know... What happens when its multiplied by x?

Comment: @NS: Sorry, that comment got sent prematurely: it was supposed to say ‘multiply [it] by $x$ and differentiate’.

Comment: Sorry for asking if its obvious but how you can get 2e from the series after differentiation?

Comment: @NS: The derivative of $xe^x$ is $(x+1)x^x$; now substitute $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that $n^2=n(n-1)+n$ and consider $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{ n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{ n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{ n!}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ n!}x^n$$ $$S=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{ n!}x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{ n!}x^{n-1}$$ and recognize that the first summation is the second derivative of $e^x$ and that the second summation is the first derivative of $e^x$ and you know them. Then, at the end, replace $x$ by $1$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^k}{n!}~=~B_k\cdot e,~$ where $B_k$ is the $k^{th}$ [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), and the identity in question

is called [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski's_formula). They are all integers for integer values of *k*, and the sequence they

form can be found on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000110).