# The value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{(2n+1)!}$, where $k\in\mathbb{W}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

It had been shown that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{4}(2e+\cosh(1)).$$

Later on, I calculated that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^3}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{8}(7e+\cosh(1))$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^4}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{16}(25e+2\sinh(1))$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^5}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{32}(97e+9\sinh(1))$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^6}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{1}{64}(434e+9\sinh(1))$$

I used Ahmed S. Attaalla's method, and for more detail please visit [How to evaluate $1+\frac{2^2}{3!}+\frac{3^2}{5!}+\frac{4^2}{7!}+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917988/how-to-evaluate-1-frac223-frac325-frac427-cdots).

Are numbers such as $7,25,97,434$ related to the Bell's Number? Is here a pattern or general formula for 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: What's $\displaystyle\mathbb{W}$ ?.

Comment: I think it represents whole numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$A_k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^k}{(2n+1)!}$$
and
$$A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A_k}{k!}t^k.$$
Then
\begin{align}
A(t)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^k}{k!}t^k
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{(n+1)t}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&=e^{t/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{(2n+1)t/2}}{(2n+1)!}
=e^{t/2}\sinh(e^{t/2})
=e^{t/2}\frac{\exp(e^{t/2})-\exp(-e^{{t/2}})}2.
\end{align}

From a classical formula,
$$\exp(e^t)=e\sum_{k=0}^\infty B_k\frac{t^k}{k!}$$
with $B_k$ the $k$-th Bell number.
A less well-known formula is
$$\exp(-e^t)=e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty R_k\frac{t^k}{k!}$$
with $R_k$ the $k$-th [Rao Uppuluri-Carpenter](http://oeis.org/A000587) number.

Then we eventually get
$$A_k=\frac{e}{2^k}\sum_{0\le r<k/2}{k\choose 2r+1}B_{2r+1}
-\frac{e^{-1}}{2^k}\sum_{0\le r<k/2}{k\choose 2r+1}R_{2r+1}.$$

Comment: Can explain it how derived last formula `A[k]`? Thanks.

Comment: It's just extracting the coefficient of $t^k/k!$ in the formula got for $A(t)$.

Comment: In Mathematica I tired `A[k_] := E/2^k*
   Sum[Binomial[k, 2 r + 1]*BellB[2 r + 1], {r, 0, k/2}] - 
  1/(E*2^k)*Sum[Binomial[k, 2 r + 1]*BellB[2 r + 1, -1], {r, 0, k/2}];A[2] // N(*1.5430806348152437*)` ,but correct answer is for `k=2`-> `1.74491` ?