# Evaluation of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{5n+1}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to evaluate series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{5n+1}{(2n+1)!}$$
I tried to split the summation...but I failed. Please help

Comment: Is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(5n%2B1)%2F(2n%2B1)!,+n%3D0+to+inf) the sum you're trying to evaluate?

Comment: Yes. Summation n running from 0 to infinity

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22/576978#576978

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $$5n+1 = \frac{5}{2}(2n+1)  - \frac{3}{2}$$

Do you know $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)!}$ ?

Comment: Thank you. We can group the terms accordingly to get the answer $\frac{e}{2}+\frac{2}{e}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sinh x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\sinh x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
let $x\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sinh \sqrt{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

let $x\rightarrow x^5$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^5}}\sinh \sqrt{x^5}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{5n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
multiply by $x$
$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^5}}\sinh \sqrt{x^5}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{5n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^5}}\sinh \sqrt{x^5})'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(5n+1)x^{5n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
then let $x=1$ to get the sum