# $S=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k^{2}-2}{k!}, n\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, summation

$$S=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k^{2}-2}{k!}, n\geq 2$$

I got $S=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{(k-2)!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{k!}$

I give k values but not all terms are vanishing.I remain with $\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$

The sum should be $2-e+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$

Comment: Why you think the sum should be $2-e+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$? Note that $S$ is a rational number but $2-e+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$ is't.

Comment: Because when I gave k values, I remained with S=2-e+  that sum

Comment: And I don't know how to calculate that sum, to obtain a rational number

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22

Comment: @Qurultray get rid of that line of thinking - it's totally wrong. For example we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\not\in\Bbb  Q$$ while $k\in\Bbb N \implies k^{-2} \in \Bbb Q$

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes but this has to do with limits and the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is not complete. In the question there is no limit and hence the numbers are actually rationals (and turns out they also converge to rational number $3$).

Answer (score 4):

For the sum until the index $n$, you can apply the same trick :
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{k^2-2}{k!} &= \sum_{k=2}^n \left[\frac{k (k-1)}{k!} + \frac{k}{k!}-\frac{2}{k!} \right]\\
&= \color{blue}{\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{k (k-1)}{k!}} + \color{orange}{\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{k!}}-\color{green}{\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{2}{k!}}\\
&= \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{k!}} + \color{orange}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k!} - 1 + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}}- \color{green}{2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k!} + 2+2-\frac{2}{n!}-\frac{2}{(n-1)!}}\\
&= 3-\frac{2}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}
\end{align*}

When $n$ tends to $\infty$, this converges to $3$.

Comment: I think the question of the OP is about the sum from $2$ to $n$, not $2$ to $\infty$. One gets the limit you obtained plus an error term

Comment: In my book, the final answer is $S=2$

Comment: I don't understand the blue part transition.From k(k-1)/k! how you get just 1/k! ? What's the difference if there is n or infinity ?

Comment: He got $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-2)!}$, and then changed the initial index from $2$ to $0$.

Comment: @DaniVaja, fro the blue part: $k(k-1)/k!=1/(k-2)!$ then, make $j=k-2$ note that the indices of the sum changed from $k=0 to \infty$ to $j=2 to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left( {{1 \over {\left( {k - 2} \right)!}} + {1 \over {\left( {k - 1} \right)!}} - {2 \over {k!}}} \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 2} {{1 \over {k!}} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {{1 \over {k!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {{2 \over {k!}}} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 1 + 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 2} {{1 \over {k!}}}  + 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 2} {{1 \over {k!}}}
  + {1 \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}} - 2\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n - 2} {{1 \over {k!}}}  + {1 \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}} + {1 \over {n!}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 3 - {1 \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}} - {2 \over {n!}} = 3 - {{n + 2} \over {n!}} \cr} 
$$
 and it **checks** with the original sum, which in fact is rational and cannot include $e$.
So something is wrong somewhere in your notes.

Comment: I splited in 2 sums.I know that sum of 1/k! tends to e.In my book the inital sum is 2