# Infinite sum $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {n( n+1)^{2}}{(n-1)!}x^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

I want to calculate the following.
$$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {n( n+1)^{2}}{(n-1)!}x^{n}=?$$
I knew.
$$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {x^{n}}{(n-1)!}=e^{x}x$$

By the way, answer is [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%CE%A3%5Bk%3D1%2C%E2%88%9E%5D%7Bk%28k%2B1%29%5E2%7D%2F%28k-1%29%21*x%5Ek&lang=ja)!
Please tell me how to solve.

Comment: Hint: Try differentiating both the sides of the expression for $x e^x$. Do you observe a pattern? Can you use this to obtain the required expression?

Comment: [display mode TeX in title is discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Write $$n(n+1)^2=(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+a(n-1)(n-2)+b(n-1)\ \ \ \ (1)$$

so that $$\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}{(n-1)!}x^n=x^4\cdot\dfrac{x^{n-4}}{(n-4)!}+ax^3\cdot\dfrac{x^{n-3}}{(n-3)!}+bx^2\cdot\dfrac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}$$

Now put $n=2$ and $n=1$ to find $a,b$

Finally $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}=e^y$$

**See also**: [Evaluate the series $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{n+2}{2(n-1)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22/576978#576978)

Comment: @SameerBaheti, Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I understood.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by powers of $x$ and differentiate iteratively
\begin{align*}
\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}&=e^x\\
\frac{d}{dx}\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {x^{n}}{(n-1)!}&=\frac{d}{dx}(xe^x)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {nx^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{d}{dx}(xe^x)\right)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {n(n+1)x^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{d}{dx}(xe^x)\right)\right)\\
\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\frac {n( n+1)^{2}}{(n-1)!}x^{n}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\frac{d}{dx}(xe^x)\right)\right)
\end{align*}
Don't forget to check the limits of $n$ at each iteration, in that constant terms become $0$ after differentiation. No need to worry about this now for we are multiplying $x$(s) before differentiating *once* every time.

Comment: Thank you very much!