# Sum of infinite series $\frac{k(k+1)3^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Can someone suggest how to find the infinite series sum for

$$\frac{k(k+1)3^k}{k!}$$ where k goes from $1$ to infinity.

I know that $\sum_0\frac{3^k}{k!}=e^3$ but I'm not sure if that helps here.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576976/evaluate-the-series-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-i-1n-fracn22/576978#576978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{k(k+1)3^k}{k!}=\frac{k(k-1)3^k}{k!}+\frac{2k3^k}{k!}=\frac{3^k}{(k-2)!}+2\frac{3^k}{(k-1)!}\\
=9\frac{3^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}+6\frac{3^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
Now change variables

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:let $$f(x)=xe^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k!}$$ what is $3f''(3)?$

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll take it from here. However, could you tell me how to approach these problems in general? How does one "know" which derivative to consider?

Comment: @PGupta the $k(k+1)$ told me that i would have to twice differentiate $x^{k+1}$ then i used the formula you gave.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @PGupta glad to have helped